# Pycharm is running script headless successfully but terminal throwing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, system-variable

Hello all,

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
dr = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
dr.get("url")

cWait = WebDriverWait(dr, 5)
usernameField = cWait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "txtUserID")))
```

while running the above set  of lines of code, when i click on pycharm run for this python file, it works in headless in good way but when I use
terminal and write code something like

`python main.py`

the console gives this output

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 92.0.4515
Get LATEST driver version for 92.0.4515
Driver [C:\Users\bc62700\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\92.0.4515.107\chromedriver.exe] found in cache

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53298/devtools/browser/b967343c-b07a-43a3-8d1f-d8b41e62e50d
[0906/071237.616:INFO:CONSOLE(19)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'txtUserID' of undefined", source: URL (19)
```

It is working absolutely fine with pycharm run button, but not with terminal
please help as because of this reason I am not able to make this as schedular event.

Comment: Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

When you run it from within pycharm, it is using a specific python, which may be different from your system's default python. Check the run configuration in pycharm and see what the path is to the python version it is using, and try to execute it using the full path to that python, i.e. instead of `python main.py` it would be something like `/path/to/your/project/venv/bin/python /path/to/your/project/main.py`

If that's not it, try giving us a more complete explanation of your situation, so that someone can try to reproduce what's happening and investigate further.

Comment: thank you for the comment, I have used the complete path of python also but same result is coming. If there is some issue with python then why it worked like downloading chrome driver and something like that ?, it should have failed in initial stage only